# ResultSet stuck looping on first row

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I am doing a simple query which I know is good and syntactically correct (no exceptions caught on executing it and the `ResultSet` is returned).

However when I pass this result set to a method to loop through it and perform some operations, the program is stuck looping on the first row in this result set (infinite loop). I really can't figure out what this problem could be. If the query is good, the `ResultSet` has the right results (I can't see what's inside it via debug as such but it should be correct) so what can be the problem?

This is the code for a better picture of what I'm doing.

```
ResultSet rs3 = null;

if (linked == J.LINKED_TO_ORG) {
    Vector<Integer> linkedTicketIds = new Vector<Integer>();

    while (rs.next()){
        // returns a set of id's for linked tickets
        Vector<Integer> linkedToTicket = Ticket.get_linked_OrgTickets(con, rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_ID)); 

        if (!linkedToTicket.isEmpty()) {                                
            // if there are linked tickets in the result set, add them to vector
            // so they can be outputted alone
            linkedTicketIds.add(rs.getInt(Ticket.FLD_ID));
        }
    }

    if (!linkedTicketIds.isEmpty()){
        rs3 = select_linked_or_unlinked(con, linkedTicketIds, select_from);                 
    }
}
```

In `select_linked_or_unlinked` method the following query is built using a string buffer and the vector linkedTicketIds which returns good results as shown (formatting added to improve readability):

```
SELECT Tick.ID
     , Tick.DESCRIPTION
     , Tick.TICKETTYPE
     , States.SHORT_NAME as state
     , Pri.DESCRIPTION   as priority
     , Owners.Login      as Owner
     , Submitters.Login  as Submitter
     , types.SHORT_NAME  as type
     , Tick.TITLE
     , Proj.Name         as Project
     , Proj.ID
     , Tick.RELEASE_NUM  as Release
     , Tick.SUBMIT_DATE
     , Tick.CUSTOMER
     , rownumber() OVER (ORDER BY Pri.ZORDER DESC)
                         as ROW_NEXT   
  FROM HOBTRACK.Tickets_Customers_View Tick
     , HOBTRACK.PROJECTS               Proj
     , HOBTRACK.PRIORITIES             Pri
     , HOBTRACK.STATES                 States
     , HOBTRACK.USERS                  Owners
     , HOBTRACK.USERS                  Submitters
     , HOBTRACK.TICKETTYPES            types
     , HOBTRACK.SECURITY_LEVEL         Security   
 WHERE Tick.ID IN (25031,25100,18123)
```

This is how the query is executed and returned:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); // where con is the connection
rs = stmt.executeQuery(above_query); 

return rs;
```

Finally, the returned result set rs3 is passed to a method where `while (rs.next())` is used to loop through this result set and perform operations. This is where the program gets stuck.  Any Ideas on what can be the problem or how can I identify it?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you post the part where your code loops infinitely?

Comment: that method is used for many other resultsets and has been used without problems for years. it's quite a long method which loops by using while(rs.next()) brings out the fields of that row and builds a table row in html

Comment: Have you tested running the query in an SQL client? It's more likely that the query is returning more rows than you assume (especially since you're doing cross-joins), so it looks to you like it's "looping" the first row.
Do a select count(*) to see how many rows are returned.

Comment: Sound advice.  From the desription of `ResultSet` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) it is impossible to loop infinitely on `rs.next()`.  But if the result set is large it may take a long time to build the html table.

Comment: Indeed, looping on rs.next() would indicate a serious bug in the JDBC driver, and that's not very likely. I believe the problem here is using cross-joins instead of inner joins.

Comment: Your statement creates a cartesian products between 8 tables. I'm almost 100% sure that is **not** what you want. You are missing the join conditions for all tables - and you should start using explicit `JOIN` syntax (that way you could not have missed the joins in the first place)

Comment: yes you were right Kayaman! It actually was returning a lot of identical records! Thanks for your help! At least I identified the problem :)